# ignore Null Values when iterating through fields with python

Tags: python, arcpy, fields-attributes

So far I have a code which iterates through Fefature Classes and ignores all fields of type String, Geometry and OID.

I now try to add some lines which tell python to ignore all NULL values when looping through an integer/float/double field. I work with ArcGIS 10.1
Any ideas how to do so? I believe it must be with SearchCursor but I do not know how.

```
for FCLASS in FCs:

#Skip all Text. OID and Geometry Fields - unfortunately WID, Shape Area etv is still included
AllFields = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(FCLASS)]
LeaveOutField = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(FCLASS,field_type='String')]
LeaveOutField.extend([f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(FCLASS,field_type='Geometry')])
LeaveOutField.extend([f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(FCLASS,field_type='OID')])
attrlist = [x for x in AllFields if x not in LeaveOutField]

# text element that has to change (e.g. title...)
title = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT", "map_title")[0]
for attr in attrlist:
    rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(attr, "row IS NOT NULL")
    for row in rows:
         if attr["*"] is not None:
             #Do Stuff here
```

Comment: It's the *value* of the field that contains NULL not the field itself... you need to skip these inside the cursor like if row[n] != None: (equivalent to not IsDBNull(row[n]) in arcobjects). If you want to skip the rows that do contain null values then use the whereclause "ExampleField is not NULL"... does that explain it?

Comment: I edited my code with how I think you mean it, it gives me an IOError..

Comment: Let me rephrase what @MichaelMiles-Stimson said, in cursors the main processing unit is the rows or records. More clearly, by a cursor, you can iterate through rows (not columns/fields) while collecting values from the desired fields. There are a few issues in your code as well. 1.There are more efficient ways of listing desired fields, 2.To be able to get a result from your "row IS NOT NULL" SQL statement, you should have a field named "row", which I do not think the case, 3.attrlist is a list and attr is an element from that (a string of course), therefore attr["*"] will throw an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NULL values are in the table, not in the fields, the check for NULL occurs in the loop or when you create the cursor using a whereclause:

```
for FCLASS in FCs:

    #Skip all Text. OID and Geometry Fields - unfortunately WID, Shape Area etv is still included
    AllFields = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(FCLASS)]
    LeaveOutField = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(FCLASS,field_type='String')]
    LeaveOutField.extend([f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(FCLASS,field_type='Geometry')])
    LeaveOutField.extend([f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(FCLASS,field_type='OID')])
    attrlist = [x for x in AllFields if x not in LeaveOutField]

    # text element that has to change (e.g. title...)
    title = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT", "map_title")[0]
    dQ = ["%s is not NULL" % F for F in attrlist]
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(FCLASS, attrlist, ' and '.join (dQ)) as rows:
        # all of these rows do not contain NULL values
        for row in rows:
            # do your stuff here safe knowning that no null values exist
```

Building the definition query dynamically with the fields... let's have a look at that interactively:

```
>>> attrlist = ['one','two','three']
>>> dQ = ["%s is not NULL" % F for F in attrlist]
>>> print dQ
['one is not NULL', 'two is not NULL', 'three is not NULL']
>>> print ' and '.join (dQ)
one is not NULL and two is not NULL and three is not NULL
```

Or while you're iterating the row:

```
for FCLASS in FCs:

    #Skip all Text. OID and Geometry Fields - unfortunately WID, Shape Area etv is still included
    AllFields = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(FCLASS)]
    LeaveOutField = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(FCLASS,field_type='String')]
    LeaveOutField.extend([f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(FCLASS,field_type='Geometry')])
    LeaveOutField.extend([f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(FCLASS,field_type='OID')])
    attrlist = [x for x in AllFields if x not in LeaveOutField]

    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(FCLASS, attrlist) as rows:
        chkRange = range(len(attrlist))
        for row in rows:
            ContainsNull = False
            for Index in chkRange:
                if row[Index] == None:
                    ContainsNull = True
                    break
            if not ContainsNull:
                # this row doesn't contain any null values
```

Answer (score 2):

In you're code you're using a field name as the dataset parameter in your search cursor. Search cursors are a means of accessing data from a table.

Try instead:

```
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(FCLASS)
for row in rows:
    #Get field value
    value = row.getValue (attr)
    #Check if value is null
    if value == None:
        #skip row
        continue
    #Do Stuff here
```

Comment: The code works.. but can you explain me why it skips the Null values? Because as I understand it *if value == None: continue* should only take rows with a Null value, what am I missing here?

Comment: You might be a bit confused about what continue does in Python. It doesn't mean continue to the next line, but instead continue the next iteration of the loop it occurs within.